# Bi-variate polynomial (2-D Matrix) multiplication: Not much gains in performance when mexing using CPP compared to Matlab

Tags: matrix, mex, matrix-multiplication

I looked around the forum but could't find the answer to my specific problem.

**Objective**

To compute A(x,y)^N where N is large - say 500. I store A(x,y) in Matlab the form of matrix where A(x,y)=\sum A(i+1,j+1)* x^i * y^j. Critical point to note is that I can't compute the real values of the coefficients because the coefficients are huge. So at each step I just store log of the coefficients so that I will always store the exponents of the coefficients but not the actual values which is important to me. If not this complication things would have been much easier i guess.

I am attaching the code here. For the power values small i.e n=50,100 instead of 500 I am seeing 1.5x faster with C-Mex code. But for values like n=500, I observe that Mex function is atmost same as Matlab if not slower. Is that the best I can do with cpp Mex file. I am not very experienced at cpp so I am hoping that some experienced users can point out any inefficiencies in my cpp code.

**Matlab Code:**

```
C=log(A);
P1=log(1);
n=500;
for i=1:n
 P1=log_MatMat(P1,C,zeroApprox);
 %P1=reshape(log_MatMat_CPP(P1,C,zeroApprox),size(P1,1)+size(C,1)-1,[]); %Using the cpp mex file.
end
```

**Matlab Function:log_MatMat**

```
function OP=log_MatMat(A,B,zeroApprox)
xDeg1=size(A,1)-1;
yDeg1=size(A,2)-1;
xDeg2=size(B,1)-1;
yDeg2=size(B,2)-1;

OP=-Inf*ones(xDeg1+xDeg2+1,yDeg1+yDeg2+1);
[xAInd,yAInd]=find(A~=-Inf);
linAInd=sub2ind(size(A),xAInd,yAInd)';
[xBInd,yBInd]=find(B~=-Inf);

  for i=0:numel(xBInd)-1
    xdegOffset=xBInd(i+1)-1 ;
    ydegOffset=yBInd(i+1)-1 ; 

    tmp=A(linAInd)+B(xBInd(i+1),yBInd(i+1));
    opIndx=xAInd+xdegOffset;
    opIndy=yAInd+ydegOffset;
    opIndLin=sub2ind(size(OP),opIndx,opIndy)';

    maxExp=max([OP(opIndLin);tmp]);
    diffExp=abs(OP(opIndLin)-tmp);

    for j=1:numel(tmp)
      % Does the addition in Log-domain without converting the values into real domain. e^x+e^y=e^y*(1+e^(x-y));
       if maxExp(j)<zeroApprox
            OP(opIndx(j),opIndy(j))=-Inf;
        else
           if OP(opIndx(j),opIndy(j))==-Inf
                 OP(opIndx(j),opIndy(j))=tmp(j);
           elseif diffExp(j)>20
                  OP(opIndx(j),opIndy(j))=maxExp(j);
           else OP(opIndx(j),opIndy(j))=maxExp(j)+log(1+exp(-1*diffExp(j)));
           end
        end
      end
    clear tmp;   
end
```

**Mex Code:**

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#define MIN(a, b) ((a < b) ? a : b)
#define MAX(a, b) ((a > b) ? a : b)
#define A(i,j) a[i+j*Xa]
#define B(i,j) b[i+j*Xb]
#define C(i,j) c[i+j*Xc]
const double Inf = std::numeric_limits <double> ::max();
int zeroApprox;

/* Addition in log-domain */
double logAdd(double x, double y)
{
    double z;
    if(x>y) {
        (x-y>20)?(z=x):(z=x+log(1+exp(y-x)));
    }
    else if (y>=x){
        (y-x>20)?(z=y):(z=y+log(1+exp(x-y)));
    }
    if (z<zeroApprox)
        z=-Inf;
    return z;
}


/* The bivariate polynomial product routine: c(x,y)=a(x,y)*b(x,y) */
void matProduct(double *a,double *b,double *c,int Xa,int Ya,int Xb, int Yb)
{
    int opX,opY;
    int Xc, Yc;
    unsigned int nonInfA[Xa*Ya][3];
    bool cInf_Flag[Xa+Xb-1][Ya+Yb-1];

    Xc=Xa+Xb-1;
    Yc=Ya+Yb-1;
    /* Initializing C with -Inf*/
    for (int i=0; i< Xc;i++){
        for (int j=0; j< Yc;j++) {
            C(i,j)=-Inf;
        }
    }

    /* Matrix Mult in Log- domain  */
    for (int jX=0; jX<Xb; jX++) {
        for(int jY=0; jY<Yb; jY++) {
            if (!isinf(B(jX,jY))) {

                for (int iX=0; iX<Xa; iX++) {
                    for (int iY=0; iY<Ya; iY++) {
                        if (!isinf(A(iX,iY))) {
                            opX=iX+jX;   opY=iY+jY;
                            C(opX,opY)=logAdd(C(opX,opY),A(iX,iY)+B(jX,jY));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int nrowsA,nrowsB,ncolsA, ncolsB; /* size of Matrices */
    int nrowsC,ncolsC;              /* size of output Matrix */
    double *outMatrix;              /* output matrix */
    double *A, *B;

    /* create a pointer to the real data in the input matrix  */
    A = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    B  = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    zeroApprox = mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);

    /* get dimensions of the input matrix */
    nrowsA = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    ncolsA = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

    nrowsB = mxGetM(prhs[1]);
    ncolsB = mxGetN(prhs[1]);

    /* Compute output dimensions*/
    nrowsC=nrowsA+nrowsB-1;
    ncolsC=ncolsA+ncolsB-1;
    /* create the output matrix */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,nrowsC*ncolsC,mxREAL);

    /* get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix */
    outMatrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    /* call the computational routine */
    if (ncolsA<=ncolsB){
        matProduct(B,A,outMatrix,nrowsB,ncolsB,nrowsA,ncolsA);
    }
    else {
        matProduct(A,B,outMatrix,nrowsA,ncolsA,nrowsB,ncolsB);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should use `std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` instead of `max()` (maximum _finite_ value).  I don't think `isinf` will work as expected otherwise.  Have you verified the correctness of your codes?

Comment: I had my doubts about Inf and isinf s you've mentioned but I verified the correctness and there doesn't seem to be any problem.

Comment: But that may be why it's slow. `max()` definitely won't be true with `isinf`. Use a debugger and step through